# If a readied ranged attack action is used against the appearance of a burrowing creature, does the attack provoke an attack of opportunity?

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack, readied-action, ranged-attack

In a recent D&D 4e session the characters readied an action, with the condition being the appearance of a burrowing creature from the ground.

Suddenly the creature burst from the ground in front of them, and the characters got to make their readied attacks, which were ranged attacks.

Does the creature get to make opportunity attacks against any triggering ranged attacks, if it appears in melee range?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The characters provoke opportunity attacks as normal, however **the creature who's turn it is does not get an opportunity attack against the readied action**

A readied action[<sup>DDI</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=332) is an immediate reaction to the triggering action, and so in this case takes places during the creature's turn.

Opportunity actions <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=119)</sup> cannot be taken during your own turn.

Answer (score 4):

If the normal usage of the ranged attack would provoke an opportunity attack then the readied action would do the same when triggered. As a D.M. I would rule that the O.A. would only happen if you use the attack.  So if the burrowing creature never appears in the round, you wouldn't use the attack, there for no O.A. triggered.

As for the actual creature bursting through I would say no, they do not get an O.A. because they can not get and O.A. during their turn.  The triggered action would happen as it emerges so clearing the burrow is movement.